# Error on where clauses at top level sequelize v5

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I hope that you can help me finding the solution to this problem.

Basically what this query does is load elements from a table called 'jobs' with multiple conditions. The conditions are load by related market, status of the job, keywords and ordering.

The snippet looks like this:

```
          sequelize.models.jobs.findAll( {
            offset: ( filters.page * filters.size ) - filters.size,
            limit: filters.size,
            where: [
              {
                status:"approved"
              }
            ],
            include: [
              {
                model: sequelize.models.users,
                attributes: [
                  'id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'phoneNumber', 'email', 'profilePicture'
                ],
                required: false
              }
            ]
          } )
```

If you notice there is a relationship that is loading called users and everything works perfectly ( like a charm I can say ). but the problem comes when I try to do some where clauses at the top level of the query. For example if I add this in the where the whole logic broke:

```
{
 status: "approved",
 '$users.firstName$': "Put a name here"
}
```

Sequelize generated query:

```
 SELECT `jobs`.*, `users`.`id` AS `users.id`, `users`.`firstName` AS `users.firstName`, `users`.`lastName` AS `users.lastName`, `users`.`phoneNumber` AS `users.phoneNumber`, `users`.`email` AS `users.email`, `users`.`profilePicture` AS `users.profilePicture`, `users->jobWorkers`.`workerId` AS `users.jobWorkers.workerId`, `users->jobWorkers`.`jobId` AS `users.jobWorkers.jobId`, `users->jobWorkers`.`hours` AS `users.jobWorkers.hours`, `users->jobWorkers`.`wage` AS `users.jobWorkers.wage`, `users->jobWorkers`.`bonus` AS `users.jobWorkers.bonus`, `users->jobWorkers`.`paid` AS `users.jobWorkers.paid`, `users->jobWorkers`.`createdAt` AS `users.jobWorkers.createdAt`, `users->jobWorkers`.`updatedAt` AS `users.jobWorkers.updatedAt`, `users->jobWorkers`.`deletedAt` AS `users.jobWorkers.deletedAt` FROM (SELECT `jobs`.`id`, `jobs`.`rate`, `jobs`.`discount`, `jobs`.`drivingFee`, `jobs`.`bonus`, `jobs`.`token`, `jobs`.`type`, `jobs`.`jobDateTime`, `jobs`.`jobStartTimestamp`, `jobs`.`laborjacks`, `jobs`.`hours`, `jobs`.`adminNotes`, `jobs`.`description`, `jobs`.`contactName`, `jobs`.`contactPhone`, `jobs`.`contactEmail`, `jobs`.`multipleLocations`, `jobs`.`startAddressStreet1`, `jobs`.`startAddressStreet2`, `jobs`.`startAddressStreet3`, `jobs`.`startAddressCity`, `jobs`.`startAddressState`, `jobs`.`startAddressZip`, `jobs`.`endAddressStreet1`, `jobs`.`endAddressStreet2`, `jobs`.`endAddressStreet3`, `jobs`.`endAddressCity`, `jobs`.`endAddressState`, `jobs`.`endAddressZip`, `jobs`.`specialInstructions`, `jobs`.`hearAboutUs`, `jobs`.`status`, `jobs`.`tip`, `jobs`.`typeOther`, `jobs`.`createdAt` FROM `jobs` AS `jobs` WHERE (`jobs`.`deletedAt` IS NULL AND (((`jobs`.`description` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`contactName` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`contactEmail` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`startAddressCity` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`startAddressState` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`startAddressStreet1` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`startAddressStreet2` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`startAddressStreet3` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`startAddressZip` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`endAddressState` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`endAddressStreet1` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`endAddressStreet2` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`endAddressStreet3` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`endAddressZip` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`specialInstructions` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `jobs`.`adminNotes` LIKE '%Daniel%' OR `users`.`firstName` = 'Daniel') AND `jobs`.`status` = 'active'))) LIMIT 0, 10) AS `jobs` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `jobWorkers` AS `users->jobWorkers` INNER JOIN `users` AS `users` ON `users`.`id` = `users->jobWorkers`.`workerId`) ON `jobs`.`id` = `users->jobWorkers`.`jobId` AND (`users`.`deletedAt` IS NULL)
```

Sequelize error:

> Unknown column 'users.firstName' in 'where clause'

If you can see sequelize add the users.firstName inside the jobs **WHERE** instead of the Left Outer Join. This is a many to many relationship with a junction table named JobWorkers, the configurations are:

> sequelize.models.jobs.belongsToMany( sequelize.models.users, { through: sequelize.models.jobWorkers, foreignKey: 'jobId'} );

> sequelize.models.users.belongsToMany( sequelize.models.jobs, { through: sequelize.models.jobWorkers, foreignKey: 'workerId' } );

I don't know what to do. Do I need to set an option in the findAll function or something else? The table relationships are wrong? I had tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Thank you for reading all this thread, if there is something I did not explained or if it is confusing please let me know.

Comment: Using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and a condition in `WHERE` on a column from a table indicated in `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is equals to `INNER JOIN`. So what do you actually try to achieve?

Comment: try `subQuery: false` in `findAll`.

Comment: @Emma I already try the si query: false, but with the same result

Comment: @Anatoly I want check if a user name inside a job is equal to the keyword I sent. So basically if the child of this query has related data bring me the parent. You know?

Comment: You should use `Sequelize.literal` with subquery in `where` to check against `users` because you use `limit` and `offset`.

Comment: @Anatoly I'll try that!